# Determining the length from any random element to the last element in a last (inside a list)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say I have a list `my_list = [[3, 0, 2, 1, 5, 4], [5, 2, 1, 3, 0, 4]]` . For each of the two lists inside `my_list` how do I find the distance(in terms of the list's length) from any random element of the list to the the end of the list. For example, if I pick `rande = 3` for the list, then I will get the following output:

```
5
2
```

How do I code this in the whilst having the most efficient time complexity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my_list = [[3, 0, 2, 1, 5, 4], [5, 2, 1, 3, 0, 4]]
rande = 3  # for this example
distances = [len(L) - L.index(rande) -1 for L in my_list]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
LL = [[3, 0, 2, 1, 5, 4], [5, 2, 1, 3, 0, 4]]

range for 5

>>> list(map(lambda x: len(x) - x.index(5) -1,LL))

[1, 5]
```